# Unable to create additional cluster member in IBM WAS ND 8.5.5

Tags: cluster, ibm, websphere

I have server1 on a node, and server2 on another node. I created a cluster (OCHCluster1).

If I add server1 to the cluster (irrespective of the clone basis I choose), it adds successfully. If I attempt to add server2 as another cluster member, I get this error:

> There is already a server with the name 'servername' on the same node,
>   server names must be unique within a node.

The same error occurs if I add server2 first before adding server1.

If I add server2 choosing an inappropriate node name, I am able to add it (which is wrong), then I attempt to edit it to the correct node name, I get the error.

If I use wsadmin to delete the cluster member, I get

> ADMG9235E: cannot find cluster member

and then I attempt to create it, I get

> ADMG9217E: Server already exist on node.

Please help with suggestions on what to do. Thank you.